# Solidity | How to throw "string" argument using Send() function?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

I have a function which get a parameter as String and compare it like below.

```
function freezeAccount(string _value) onlyOwner public {
    if (keccak256(_value) == keccak256("true")){ isFrozen = "true"; }
    if (keccak256(_value) == keccak256("false")){ isFrozen = "false"; }
}
```

Above is my smart contract code. 
I wanna use this my method using web3 so I'm trying to make transition by `send()` function like below.

```
export const setFreezeAccount = value => {
console.log("setFreezeAccount :: value: ", value);
  const str = value.toString();

  myContract.methods
  .freezeAccount(str)
  .send({ from: TOKENOWNER })
  .then(receipt => {
    console.log("setFreezeAccount :: receipt: ", receipt);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("setFreezeAccount :: err: ", err);
  });
};
```

The freezeAccount() function is working well on Remix IDE but the `Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""`  error returned When I execute the setFreezeAccount() function.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. I want to delete this question but I will remain it for other people who make same mistake like me. The reason why error occurred was the `freezeAccount()` function on Solidity is only can executed by owner. I added the access modifier named `onlyOwner` so that I have to make transaction data and signed it then send the transaction using Web3.

Comment: You're also a good sport.